# EXT-JS 4.2.1 retain the current Position of scrollbar of form - panel

Tags: javascript, extjs, scrollbar, sencha-architect

I am trying to retain the position of the scrollbar in formpanel to show after form refresh .
But i am unable to find any solution.Please help me by suggesting solution for this.
Thanks & Regards
 Sumanth K.P

Comment: U might need to give more details about your problem. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with a grid panel in IE, where on a refresh the grid would scroll to the start of the grid.
The solution was to add the following function to the grid panel:

```
    fixIeScrollPosition: function() {
        console.log("fix ie scroll position ");
        var scrollTarget = this.getScrollTarget();

        var currentScrollPosition = scrollTarget.getEl().getScroll().top;
        var expectedScrollPosition = scrollTarget.bufferedRenderer.scrollTop;

        var correction = expectedScrollPosition - currentScrollPosition; // will be 0 in non-IE

        scrollTarget.scrollBy(0,correction);

    },
```

This is triggered by refresh events.

Answer (score 0):

1-Before refreshing the panel, put the scroll position in the variable.

`var scrollposition = form.body.dom.scrollTop;`

2-So, refresh the content of the form and make the scroll position equal to the value of the previous position.

`form.body.dom.scrollTop = scrollposition ;`